# Is there a way to construct a conditional from an array?

Tags: rust

Given the following two arrays, is there a way to construct a conditional from `b` to use in a loop of values in `a` like the following code? I would like `is_divisible` to look something like `(i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0) || (i % 7 == 0)`

```
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u32> = vec![80, 90, 101, 254];
    let b: Vec<u32> = vec![3, 5, 7];

    let is_divisible = // ???

    for i in a {
        if is_divisible {
            println!("{} is true", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a closure that uses `b` and does whatever logic you need. In this case, you can use [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) and [`Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) to test if all the values meet some criteria:

```
let is_divisible = |i| {
    b.iter().any(|b| i % b == 0)
};
```

I wouldn't usually write it as a separate variable and I'd use [`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) instead of the `if`:

```
for i in a.iter().filter(|&i| b.iter().any(|&b| i % b == 0)) {
    println!("{} is true", i);
}
```